# How to share data with users nearby using google nearby

Tags: android

I am making an app where I want users to be able to share their business cards with people directly around them. ( I have the login and register done and main layout of the app done)

I want to know if there is a way for a user to see everyone's  business card directly around them with my same app

Comment: Maybe Nearby is what you're looking for: https://developers.google.com/nearby/

Answer (score 0):

Firebase doesn't have such feature.

However there are ways to do such thing. It is all about sharing data with person next to you. You can use NFC, Bluetooth, peer-to-peer WiFi or even sound waves. If I were you I would choose WiFi P2P as it is already implemented in Android, WiFi is on every device and it is pretty easy to use.

[Link to documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html)

Answer (score 0):

You want NearBy Messages - a publish / discover type of sharing
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/messages/package-summary